# Is it possible to wait for a table till all its rows loads completely

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java and WebDriver with Serenity BDD. There is a table which takes time to load. Is it possible to wait till all its rows loads completely?

Please don't mark negative. I know all those ExpectedConditions and all but seems they all wait only for the table to be present and not till its data loads completely.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ and your _code trials_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uniquely **assert** your table has finished loading.

That usually means some element has finished loading. Or the element is present (or visible, clickable...).

So, whether you know it or not, you are expecting a condition to be fulfilled. Then, why not use `ExpectedConditions`?

Just decide how can **you** (from a user's perspective) tell that the table is finished loading. For example, your expected condition can be that the last row of the table is visible.

If there is some kind of a spinner element, so the user knows the page is unresponsive, like a message "Table loading..." or similar, you can use `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated('Spinner element locator')`.

Comment: Its a dynamic table mate, data may be different each time and there is pagination. So really not sure of any such element.

Comment: Is there some kind of a spinner element, so the user knows the page is unresponsive? Like a message "Table loading..."

Comment: In that case you can use `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated()`.